# Python subprocess to call Unix commands, a question about how output is stored

Tags: python, unix, call, subprocess

I am writing a python script that reads a line/string, calls Unix, uses grep to search a query file for lines that contain the string, and then prints the results.

`from subprocess import call`

`for line in infilelines:`

```
    output = call(["grep", line, "path/to/query/file"])
    print output
    print line`
```

When I look at my results printed to the screen, I will get a list of matching strings from the query file, but I will also get "1" and "0" integers as output, and `line` is never printed to the screen.  I expect to get the lines from the query file that match my string, followed by the string that I used in my search.

Answer (score 6):

call returns the process return code.

If using Python 2.7, use check_output.

```
from subprocess import check_output
output = check_output(["grep", line, "path/to/query/file"])
```

If using anything before that, use communicate.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["grep", line, "path/to/query/file"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

This will open a pipe for stdout that you can read with communicate. If you want stderr too, you need to add "stderr=subprocess.PIPE" too.

This will return the full output. If you want to parse it into separate lines, use split.

```
output.split('\n')
```

I believe Python takes care of line-ending conversions for you, but since you're using grep I'm going to assume you're on Unix where the line-ending is \n anyway.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: +1. The extra batteries in Python 2.7 keep pleasantly surprising me.

Comment: I used the code that you wrote above.  When I print `output` I get every line from my query file, and not only those lines that match my string.   I read the documentation that you pointed to (however, I have to say I don't really understand it, and I had read it before I posted my initial question).  I am looking for a more descriptive  explanation of `communicate`.

Comment: Screwed up my code. You should get 0 lines (output should be None). I'll update with what's necessary. If you're getting every line, then you might not be using grep correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The following code works with Python >= 2.5:

```
from commands import getoutput
output = getoutput('grep %s path/to/query/file' % line)
output_list = output.splitlines()
```

Comment: Deprecated since Python 2.6. Use subprocess instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

Answer (score -2):

Why would you want to execute a call to external `grep` when Python itself can do it? This is extra overhead and your code will then be dependent on `grep`  being installed. This is how you do simple `grep` in Python with "in" operator.

```
query=open("/path/to/query/file").readlines()
query=[ i.rstrip() for i in query ]
f=open("file")
for line in f:
    if "line" in query:
        print line.rstrip()
f.close()
```

Comment: Because python can be far slower than grep when working with large files